# RabbitMQ Camel and STOMP

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, stomp

I successfully completed a POC using Spring Reactor Netty Stomp client (Spring messaging framework) to connect to RabbitMQ on port 61613 (port dedicated for STOMP). That was just a POC. Now I have to build something concrete to be able to deploy in prod environments. I was Googling Spring Messaging vs Spring Integration and stumbled upon Apache Camel.

RabbitMQ component page in the Camel documentation talks about port 5672 and that is AMQP. The STOMP component page talks about ActiveMQ.

I did not see any examples or documentation regarding Camel in conjunction with RabbitMQ and STOMP.

Can Apache Camel be used to connect to RabbitMQ on port 61613?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Camel documentation for the STOMP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/stomp-component.html) states:

> The Stomp component is used for communicating with Stomp compliant message brokers, like Apache ActiveMQ or ActiveMQ Apollo.

Notice that it says *like* Apache ActiveMQ. It doesn't say it *has to be* Apache ActiveMQ. It just uses ActiveMQ as an example of a "Stomp compliant" message broker. If RabbitMQ supports STOMP then Camel's STOMP component should work without issue.

Looking at Camel's [StompEndpoint](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/stomp/StompEndpoint.java#L95) it clearly uses the brokerURL from the configuration to make the connection to the Stomp broker. It uses the [Fusesource Stomp client implementation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-stomp/pom.xml#L46) which should work with any Stomp compliant broker.

It's also worth noting that Camel is an integration framework and Stomp is a simple, open messaging protocol so it doesn't make much sense for the Stomp component within Camel to only work with a couple of ActiveMQ brokers. It can (and will) work with any Stomp compliant broker (just as the documentation states).

Comment: RabbitMQ supports STOMP.


I am getting this exception when i try to connect to STOMP Broker
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[stomp:queue:test?brokerURL=tcp://localho... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: stomp://queue:test?brokerURL=tcp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61613&login=guest&passcode=guest due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: stomp://queue:test?brokerURL=tcp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61613&login=guest&passcode=guest due to: There are 3 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint.

Comment: Can you try removing `brokerURL=tcp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61613` from the endpoint configuration? The default value for `brokerURL` is already `tcp://localhost:61613`. See if that clears up the error.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. What i understand is, the stomp end points are of the form stomp://.... ActiveMQ supports this kind of URI. RabbitMQ doesn't. RabbitMQ has stomp plugin enabled but that works with tcp. I will try tcp as the scheme and what happens

Comment: The `stomp://` at the beginning of the Camel endpoint configuration is to tell *Camel* to use its stomp component. The actual connection it creates to the broker depends on the configuration of `brokerURL`. In any case, Stomp client implementations use TCP to communicate with a Stomp broker regardless of the schema used for their URL; that's pretty clear from the Stomp specification. Also, the error indicates that there's a problem with the endpoint configuration so it's not even attempting to create the actual connection to the Stomp broker so you can't yet say it won't work with RabbitMQ.

Comment: I looked into the camel code. The schema is used as-is. with ACtiveMQ installation it works but not with RabbitMQ. I will move ahead with Spring Messaging or Spring Integration.

Comment: What Camel code did you look at specifically, and what do you mean that the "schema is used as-is"? I just looked at Camel's [`StompEndpoint`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/stomp/StompEndpoint.java#L95) and it clearly uses the `brokerURL` from the configuration to make the connection to the Stomp broker. It uses the [Fusesource Stomp client implementation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-stomp/pom.xml#L46) which should work with any Stomp compliant broker.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Camel is an *integration framework* and Stomp is a simple, open messaging protocol so it doesn't make much sense for the Stomp component within Camel to only work with a couple of ActiveMQ brokers. It can (and will) work with any Stomp compliant broker (just as the documentation states).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was still getting unable to resolve endpoint error. Then, i tried with latest version by changing my pom.xml. This time the error message changed and it showed BAD CONNECT. I was at the least :)
Digging deeper showed that it was trying to connect to vhost as localhost. When we do not specify host as an option, it takes localhost as vhost. 

Now i should check how to set STOMP version. The document doesn't talk anything about version parameter. By default it uses version 1.1

Thank you.

Comment: I made changes to StompConfiguration and StompEndpoint classes of camel-stomp component. Built my own jar and everything seems to be ok with POC.
Will try to raise a PR so that it will be helpful to others :)

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. If not, let me know what's missing. Thanks!